# Accessories and jewellery

Tags: word-meaning, synonyms

Is jewellery included in the concept of accessories? Wikipedia gives a positive response:

> (Fashion) accessories that are worn may include jackets, boots and shoes,
>   cravats, ties, hats, bonnets, belts and suspenders, gloves, muffs,
>   **jewelry,** watches, sashes, shawls, scarves, lanyards, socks, and
>   stockings.

At the same time, Oxford Learner’s Dictionaries say that

> ...accessories are things that you can wear or carry that matches your
>   clothes, for example a belt or a bag.

A belt or a bag cannot be referred to as pieces of jewellery.

Is it correct to consider jewellery as a part of accessories? Can items of jewellery be called "accessories"?

Comment: I suspect Oxford  says "that *match* your clothes"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fashion accessories can include jewelry. For example, [this link](http://www.neimanmarcus.com/CUSP/Accessories/cat59270784/c.cat) to the Neiman-Marcus online Accessories department shows a sub-link to jewelry:

[image]

On the other hand, the Saks Fifth Avenue website separates them:

[image]

possibly because there are so many options it's easier to subdivide them, or possibly because they consider these two different categories.

Meanwhile, *Elle Magazine* titles their [online accessory page](http://www.elle.com/fashion/accessories/):

> Accessories Trends 2017 - Bags, Shoes, Jewelry and Accessories for Women

which suggests they think jewelry *is* a type of accessory.

So it seems a matter of opinion.

Comment: Well, in fashion, speak jewelry can be understood to be an accessory. But I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

I would say "cheap" jewelry definitely qualifies as "accessories." An expensive diamond ring or a natural pearl necklace much less so -- unless you're wearing an expensive designer gown and the jewelry is worn to accent the gown.

Comment: whaaat? No, no, no. In fashion speak, jewelry of any kind can be considered an accessory. It has nothing to do with cost. She went to the Oscars in a beautiful designer gown without a single accessory. [that would include jewelry].

Answer (score 1):

Taking into account the most obvious definition of the noun "**accessory**" - "*a thing that can be added to something in order to make something more useful, attractive, valuable, versatile, rich*" we can assume that even a sock can be an accessory.

Yes, you are right, the common list of accessories does include jewellery. Things like glasses, chains, or devices even are also listed as accessories.

Obviously, if we take it the extensive way then anything we wear is actually an accessory, since this 'anything' is added to our body.